# c++ code to print out a triangle with numbers and stars

Tags: c++, output

Okay, this program is supposed to take in a number as a height then print tabs. tabs = height - i. Then print a number. If the number is 1, print the number and move to the next line otherwise it should print the number then some stars (stars = 2*i - 3), then the number + 1, then go to the new line. I think I have the numbers and stars correct but I cannot figure out the tabs. I hope I explained this correctly.

Note: I am sure there are other bugs in this code but I am only focusing on this one at the moment.

I have attached the output I am getting (output with black background) and what the expected output should be (output with white background)to make things clearer.

The argument given was '5'.

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

int main() {
int space, height;

    cout <<"Enter a height (greater than 0): ";
    cin >> height;
    int v0 = height;
    int tabs = 1;
    int i = 1;
   
    
   
    for (int rows = 1, stars = 1; rows <= height; ++rows, stars = 1) {
       int the_row = rows;

       
          for (tabs = 1; tabs <= height - the_row; ++tabs) {
              ++tabs;
             cout << '\t';
            // ++the_row;
            
             
             
          }
          if (the_row == 1) {
             cout << i << '\n';
            ++the_row;
            // ++i;
            //++the_row;
            
          }
          else {
             ++the_row;
             cout << ++i;
            while (stars <= 2*rows - 3) {
               cout << "   *";
               ++stars;
            }
           
               cout << '\t' << ++i << endl;
              // ++the_row;
         }
       
    
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pur6p.png)

[This is what I want it to output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfrV8.png)

Comment: Please write your output and expected output in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this loop you are actually incremented tabs twice , so it works good (i.e. tab shifting works as per expectation) is  for even numbers of iterations i.e. happens for odd lines(e.g line 1,3,5 etc), for even lines (i.e. line 2,4 etc) the tab shifting is less.

```
for (tabs = 1; tabs <= height - the_row; ++tabs) {
          ++tabs;
         cout << '\t';
        // ++the_row;            
         
         
      }
```

Also, another problem is when you are printing '*'  you used spaces , instead use '\t'

So to get the expected output, change followings,

Change tab increment to once, i.e.

```
for (tabs = 1; tabs <= height - the_row; ++tabs) {
          // ++tabs; --> comment this
         cout << '\t';
        // ++the_row;            
         
         
      }
```

And,change print '*' line, as

```
cout << '\t' <<"*";
```

Comment: Good to see it solves your problem.  Can you mark this as answer?